# Cakephp, не сохраняет модель

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Доброе времени суток, возникла проблема странная. По порядку: есть админка, есть пользовательская часть, у обоих примерно одинаковый код сохранения, после изменения данных из формы, но в админской части, после сохранения абсолютно ничего не приходит, белая страница и код останавливается, никаких ошибок валидации, ни в дебаге, нигде. Следующая часть кода, после model->save не выполняется вообще. Проблема появилась, после переезда на 3.6 версию
Код:

```
public function edit($alias = null)
{
    if (!$alias) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Неверная ссылка'));
    }

    $link = $this->Links->findByAlias($alias)->first();
    if (!$link) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Неверная ссылка'));
    }

    $bundles = $this->Links->Bundles
        ->find('list', [
            'keyField' => 'id',
            'valueField' => 'title'
        ])
        ->where(['user_id' => $link->user_id]);

    $this->set('bundles', $bundles);


    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $link = $this->Links->patchEntity($link, $this->request->getData());
       if ($this->Links->save($link)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The Link has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $alias]);
        } else {
            //debug( $link->errors() );
            $this->Flash->error(__('Oops! There are mistakes in the form. Please make the correction.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set('link', $link);
}
```

Вот что пишется в error.log

```
Warning: The connection is going to be closed but there is an active transaction.
```

Такая проблема происходит с большей частью моделей в админке

Comment: то есть фактически на `save` просто падает, и не пишет ничего в лог, при включенном debug в конфиге? Админка и остальное работают через один коннекешен?

Comment: @teran, да,все верно, работает только удаление и модель юзера (save, delete и т.д.), а кастомные модели не работают

Comment: а с какой версии мигрировали то? Сравните что возвращает `getData` в админке и там, где работает. Плюс, в админке возможно какие то события навешиваются на сохранения/удаления и т.п. Мб там что падает?

Comment: @teran, по моему с версии 3.3, проверял все через дебагер getdata, сравнил ответ после patchEntity, а если и есть где-то события, которые навешиваются, я не знаю в какую сторону рыть, может можно как-то с вами связаться ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Был скрытый метод beforeSave, который убивал весь процесс сохранения